# How can i do an "or" query in a Model.find on Sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

i have to make a query that accept two entries from a field in Sails. Since Sails use waterline for ORM i've also tagged it on this question.

```
    Conversions.find({status : 0} || {status : 2}).exec(function(err, convs){
      // do something 
    });
```

This don't work, there is a solution using Sails/Waterline or i should go for a custom query?

Many thanks

Comment: why the -1 reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Conversions.find().where({
  or: [
    {status: 0},
    {status: 1}
  ]
  }).exec(function(err, convs){
      // do something 
});
```

Using `$or` will work, but for a `native` query, and not for waterline AFAIK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See the [query language documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Querylanguage.html?q=or-pairs) for all of the `where` clause options.